# Print list Object c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

hi i trying print a list of object , but just name of my  object

class People

```
public class Pessoa
{

        public  int ID { get; set; }
        public  int Idade { get; set; }
        public  string Nome { get; set; }

        public  List<int> Setor { get; set; }

}
```

My Main class

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    List<Pessoa> pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();

    pessoas.Add(new Pessoa
    {
        ID = 2,
        Idade = 32,
        Nome = "name",
         Setor = new List<int> { 2, 55, 32, 13, 24 }
    });

    pessoas.Add(
        new Pessoa
        {
            ID = 12,
            Idade = 24,
            Nome = "name",
             Setor = new List<int> { 2, 55, 32 }
        });

    pessoas.Add(
    new Pessoa
    {
        ID = 19,
        Idade = 29,
        Nome = "name",
          Setor = new List<int> { 2, 32 }
    });

    var teste = new Pessoa();
    foreach (var p in pessoas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);


    }


    Console.ReadKey();



}
```

return a list empty
return a list empty
return a list empty
return a list empty 
return a list empty

Comment: If you want to print the names, use `Console.WriteLine(p.Nome);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing a user defined object will not work this way. As you could read in the documentation of [Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_) it calls the "ToString()" method of the object to print and the standard implementation prints the name of the class of this object.

If you want to output the contents of your object you have to override the ToString() method.

Example:

```
   public class Pessoa {
      ....
      override ToString() {
         return $"ID = {ID}, IIdade = {Idade}, ....";
      }
   }
```